# Trouble with Network for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04

I recently bought Toshiba "satellite-L50-B1416" laptop, and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it, anyway, I have some problems with it
I couldn't find its main drivers for Ubuntu>
Second, I'm unable to connect it to the internet whether wired or wireless, and I don't know where is the problem, I guessed it is in the drivers which I'm unable to download because they're UNAVAILABLE !
How could I download them?
Or what is the matter with the network?

wireless type is Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 
and this is image of out put of
 `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'`

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.